# How do I use MOgenerator's xmod?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, core-data, mogenerator

I just installed MOgenerator 1.21 for use with Xcode 3.2.5 (on an iOS project if that's relevant).

I can run the mogenerator command from the terminal fine. But I can't seem to have xmod work.

`mdfind` reports xmod is :

```
/Developer/Library/Xcode/Plug-ins/Xmod.pbplugin
```

So it looks like it's installed correctly. I also quitted and restarted Xcode.

As documented (included in a very similar question that left me puzzled), I added "xmod" to the comment pane in my xcdatamodel info page, as illustrated in the following image:

[the comment on this window reads "xmod" http://emberapp.com/jdmuys/images/untitled/sizes/m.png](http://emberapp.com/jdmuys/images/untitled/sizes/m.png)

Now, whether I build my project, modify my xcdatamodel or both, nothing new happens: no file is generated, nor added to my project, no new output is in my build log.

So how am I supposed to "launch" xmod? Is xmod supposed to let me know somehow that it ran? Where should I look? Is it supposed to appear in a new build phase?

I am puzzled and I'm not sure what to try.

Thanks.

Comment: How to show info page? In xcode 4. If I right click a file I do not see info page.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I added a second line to the comment pane, with the `--output-dir` parameter. The comment pane now reads:

```
xmod
--output-dir MOs
```

And now it starts working: it generates the files and they show up in the Xcode project.

Why wasn't that explained anywhere? No idea...

Answer (score 2):

Xmo'd 1.21 [introduced a bug](https://github.com/rentzsch/mogenerator/commit/0894c56ed471b4c5d0d30cb312f1d8970a0dd216#L0L118) where it wouldn't create your MO src folder for you if it didn't already exist. `--output-dir` is just a work-around.

The [fix has been committed](https://github.com/rentzsch/mogenerator/commit/462a485f0686b44fbaabad875ee8a21e3e0f61bc) and will be in mogenerator/Xmo'd 1.22